# How to inject my own video frames in the android camera stream to get a test device for third party apps

Tags: android, encoding, camera

I'm looking for a way to get hands on the camera stream. Best would be right before the encoding. Any hints on how to achieve this?
The goal would be to validate third party applications.
Platform: recent rooted android devices.

Comment: You can rewrite libcamera_client.so, but it depends on the platform, so this won't be an easy task to adapt it to many devices. Also, it may be a real challenge to enable all custom features of the device-specific camera applications.